# dropw down with empty field as the first one using options for select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

Hi I have the following to display a dropdown

```
<p><%= f.select :depGroupname, options_for_select(@dep_group_name, :inlcude_blank => true) %></p>
```

Here i need the first option to be a blank one. But in the above code, the drop down start with the first element in the @dep_group_name array.

Let me know how to inlcude a blank with options_for_select tag

Thanks

Comment: You have a typo in `inlcude_blank`  , 'c' and 'l' are inverted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the include_blank part outside of the `options_for_select`

```
<p><%= f.select :depGroupname, options_for_select(@dep_group_name), {:include_blank => true} %></p>
```

You can also set the prompt for the blank by replacing true with a string

```
<p><%= f.select :depGroupname, options_for_select(@dep_group_name), {:include_blank => "Choose Your Department"} %></p>
```